# Powershell form window not allow javascript to run

Tags: javascript, html, powershell

I am having issues open a remote url inside of this power-shell form. The url works fine outside of the power-shell script. I can run it on IE Firefox or Chrome without no issues. However, inside of the form, it immediate gives java-script errors.

```
 cls
function GenerateForm {
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.drawing
#Form Setup

$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$TabControl = New-object System.Windows.Forms.TabControl
$AlertsPage = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState
#Form Parameter

$form1.Text = "Computer User Preferences and Utilities"
$form1.Name = "form1"
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$form1.BackColor = "#f5f2d0"
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$form1.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form1.ShowInTaskbar = $Formalse
$Form1.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
$Form1.MaximizeBox = $Formalse
$Form1.MinimizeBox = $Formalse
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 775
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 490
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
#Tab Control

$tabControl.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 30
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 25
$tabControl.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$tabControl.Name = "tabControl"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 450
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 725
$tabControl.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$form1.Controls.Add($tabControl)

$AlertsPage.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$AlertsPage.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$AlertsPage.Name = "AlertPage"
$AlertsPage.Text = "Alerts”
$tabControl.Controls.Add($AlertsPage)

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$webBrowser1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
#$webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = $true;
#$webBrowser1 = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$webBrowser1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(0,0)
$webBrowser1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(710,700)
$webBrowser1.URL="http://www2.lv.psu.edu/it/rss/default.html"
$AlertsPage.Controls.Add($webBrowser1)

#Save the initial state of the form
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
} #End Function
GenerateForm
```

Comment: It would help if you could give us what those "javascript errors" are. e.g. Cross Site scripting errors, or trying to access different security zones etc.

Comment: The url has a lot of javascript that also helps with running the code. The url works fine on a regular browser. But, when executing from powershell is like it does not trust the code. Then, it ask if you want to continue running the scripts js on this site. You are welcome to visit the site and see for yourself the code.

Comment: This is not a PowerShell issue, but a .Net component/control limitation. The web browser component/control is not a full web browser, and should not be expected to render or respond, in all aspects as a normal browser would. One should never expect a lightweight UI component to be anywhere close to what a fully developed browser can deliver. This would be like saying that a rich-text component/control should be able to do all things MSWord is capable of, and we all know that is not the case either.

Comment: Follow-on to my previous comment, since it's too long for one comment. ;-} This 3rdP components like this (and others like it for given use cases) exist. [DotNetBrowser (WPF / WinForms Chromium-based Browser Component)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TeamDev-Ltd.DotNetBrowserWPFWinFormsChromium-basedBrowserCompo). Lastly, WinForms is legacy, and you really want to focus on WPF for your GUI development as it is more granualr, and flexible than WF.

Comment: After doing some additional investigation, the IE browser is stopping the script to run. Am not sure if there is a way to change powershell default web browser to something like chrome or firefox.